# Taxable Sales Calculations (Tax Table)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, tax

I'm trying to wrap my head around taxable sales, non-taxable sales, and tax paid using only a view values our Point-of-Sale outputs each month.

I have Order Total and Tax as the two figures I need to work with.  The problem(s) I'm having are when some sales have taxable items and non-taxable items in the same sale.  We can always go back and look at the individual invoices for assurance, but I would prefer to be able to do this in Excel.

**Here are all the fields I'm working with:**

- Order Total(total price of sale)
- Tax (only the amount of tax paid for this Sale)
- MINUS TAX (=[@[Order total]]-[@Tax]
- ASSUMED TAXABLE (=IF([@[EXPECTED TAX]]=[@Tax],[@Tax],1/0.06*[@Tax]))
- ASSUMED NONTAXABLE (=ABS([@[ASSUMED TAXABLE]]-[@[MINUS TAX]]))
- EXPECTED TAX (=[@[MINUS TAX]]*0.06)

The issue I'm having is in some cases, when the calculations don't match up exactly because of "rounding" errors.  Here's an example:

**ORDER TOTAL:** 202.66
**TAX:** 11.47
**MINUS TAX:** 191.19
**ASSUMED TAX:** 191.17
**ASSUMED NONTAXABLE:** 0.02
**EXPECT TAX:** 11.47

Due to the calculations used, there is a margin of error in this example of $0.02.

How do I account for those margin of errors and make the *backwards calculations* (Starting with a total and working your way backwards to assume Tax and Subtotals) operate more reliably?

**EDIT:**
I totally forgot to mention that, yeah, this is all due to how Tax Tables work, but I'm not entirely sure how to fix that with Excel.

**EDIT 2:**

**ORDER TOTAL:** $82.24
**TAX:** $4.66
**MINUS TAX:** $77.58
**ASSUMED TAXABLE:** $77.67 (*=IF([@[EXPECTED TAX]]=[@Tax],[@Tax],1/0.06*[@Tax])*)

**ASSUMED NONTAXABLE:** $0.09 (*=ABS([@[ASSUMED TAXABLE]]-[@[MINUS TAX]])*)

**TAX OFF EXPECTED:** $0.00 (*=IF(ABS([@Tax]-[@[EXPECTED TAX]])<([@[Order total]]*0.06),0,(ABS([@[EXPECTED TAX]]-[@Tax])))*)
**EXPECTED TAX:** $4.65 (*=[@[MINUS TAX]]*0.06*)

Here, EXPECTED TAX is off by $0.01 from what it actually is.  Additionally, ASSUMED NONTAXABLE should be $0.00.  Also, ASSUMED TAXABLE, is way off ($0.09 - which is the ASSUMED NONTAXABLE)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your formulas in Round() (or RoundDown() or RoundUp()), which allows you to control the number of digits you want to round to (most likely 2 digits in your case). Worked for me with the numbers in your example.

Comment: Still having the same problem using ROUND().  Here's an example - Total Sale was $62.90.  Amount of tax in that number is $3.56.  Subtracting tax from the Total Sale gives us $59.34.  However, if we try to "backwards" calculate that based on the amount of tax, we get $59.33 instead of $59.34.  Wrapping the formula in ROUND() gives the same numbers. eg. ``=ROUND(IF([@[EXPECTED TAX]]=[@Tax],[@Tax],1/0.06*[@Tax]),2)``

Comment: The error is caused by the floating point precision : https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/78113/floating-point-arithmetic-may-give-inaccurate-results-in-excel. Namely here it's your 1/0.06 floating point that causes the problem. You can try the solution in the blog post, but you might as well reverse calculate the whole thing. Instead of 1/0.06, use 1/(Tax/Minus Tax)*Tax. I'd still suggest you wrap everything in Round().

Comment: That's what the formula is written to do isn't it? Bring up Tax if TRUE and calculate Minus Tax if FALSE.